# SELECT time period, SQL

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Can someone please help me? This doesn't work (I get no results):

`SELECT * FROM push WHERE Sent >= '08.00' AND Sent < '10:00'`

`Sent` contains "Dec  5, 2017 09:45 AM CET" and I would like to select everything that has a time between 08:00 and 10:00.

I've also tried things like (I get no results):

`SELECT * FROM push WHERE Sent LIKE '%09:00%'`

but the colon messes it up. I've tried // and () before and after colon, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the data type of `sent`?  Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Sorry, my tags were wrong.. sent is varchar.

Comment: I come from Udacity slack to help 

Answer (score 0):

You *should* be storing `sent` as a date/time value.  If so, you can just do something like this:

```
where hour(sent) in (8, 9)
```

Or something like this:

```
where time(sent) >= '08:00:00' and time(sent) < '10:00:00'
```

Note that the functions `hour()` and `time()` vary by database, but most support this functionality in some way.

If you are storing it as a string, then my advice is to fix the data and do one of the above.  If you are resistant to that for some reason, you can use `like`:

```
where sent like '% 08:%' or sent like '% 09:%'
```

But really, you should be storing your data using the correct types, so this may even be bad advice.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't, I get "#1292 - Incorrect datetime value: "Dec 5, 2017 09:45 AM CET" for column 'Sent' at row 1"

Comment: @anna . . . This problem should be fixed with the database is loaded.  Or, you could ask another question about fixing the data.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, but I was given this data to make a case... I think my options right now is either to make a loop that catches every minute in between 8am and 10am (but there is still the problem with colon and LIKE) or transforming a whole column from "Dec 5, 2017 09:45 AM CET" to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss, so I can convert the column to datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Use the HOUR function

```
SELECT * FROM push WHERE HOUR(sent) > 8 AND HOUR(sent) < 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

With `between` !
If `sent` is a date time:

```
SELECT * FROM push WHERE HOUR(sent) BETWEEN 8 AND 9;
```

If `sent` is a varchar:

```
SELECT * FROM push WHERE SUBSTRING(sent,-12,5) BETWEEN '08:00' AND '09:59';
```

Comment: Thank you, great idea (like slicing?), but it's not working, don't get any results back.

Comment: could you check if there is result on this `select SUBSTRING(sent,-12,5) from push` with 'HH:mm' format ?

Comment: Very strange ... in my side I got data with the same query ;\

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. I did "select SUBSTRING(sent,-12,5) from push" and then I got back 11:44
11:36
11:15
11:14
11:02
10:46

Comment: and do you have something between 8h and 10h ? (as a string) ... if yes, that's the idea

Comment: I've done `SELECT * FROM push WHERE App Notification Sends >500 AND Sent LIKE '______________9%' OR App Notification Sends >500 AND Sent LIKE '______________8%'` and I want to`and then I want to look at other columns.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping out. I solved it (in a not very beautiful way): SELECT * FROM `push` WHERE `Sent` LIKE '______________8%' maybe it would be better from the end, but I think there is an extra space if the date is just one character.